Can density matrices have transcendental off-diagonal elements?
Hello everyone,
I’ve been exploring parameterized density matrices and was curious about the conditions under which they remain valid. For example, consider the following 2x2 density matrix parameterized by $ p \in [0, 1] $:
$$
\rho = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p & \lambda(p) \\
\lambda(p) & 1-p
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the off-diagonal element $ \lambda(p) $ satisfies the positivity constraint:
$$|\lambda(p)| \leq \sqrt{p(1-p)}.
$$
Now, suppose I define the off-diagonal element as:
$$
\lambda(p) = \sin(p) \cdot p \cdot (1-p),
$$
where $\lambda(p)$ is a transcendental function of ( p ). considering that this choice ensures $|\lambda(p)| \leq \sqrt{p(1-p)} $ for all $( p \in [0, 1] )$, I have the following questions:

Does this represent a valid density matrix, given that the other constraints (Hermiticity, trace 1, and positive semi-definiteness) appear to be satisfied?
Does this idea extend to other transcendental forms for $\lambda(p)$, such as trigonometric, exponential, or other non-algebraic functions, as long as the inequality $|\lambda(p)| \leq \sqrt{p(1-p)} $ is satisfied?
How would one systematically construct density matrices with such transcendental off-diagonal elements? Are there general guidelines or examples for designing parameterized forms of $ \lambda(p) $ to ensure validity?

I would appreciate any insights, references, or examples related to this!
Thank you for your time!

If they satisy the definition of a density matrix then they are valid. There's no restriction on whether the number is transcendental or not.
